# Libsodium key exchange (shared secret) in a different ways

Tags: java, libsodium

I make android implementation of crypto messages for app.

Server side uses `crypto_kx_client_session_keys` in libsodium library for creating shared secret between client and server.

I use java designed NaCl library, where is no such method (old libsodium API usage). 
So I make shared secret within `crypto_scalarmult_curve25519` (Diffie Hellman), but final shared secret key does not match with the server's one.

My code:

```
// Shared secret generation
crypto_scalarmult_curve25519(result, serverPublicKey: PublicKey, clientSecretKey: PrivateKey) 
// Shared secret decrypt (with SecretBox)
crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305_open(message, ciphertext, ciphertext.length, nonce, sharedkey)
```

Is there any possibility to make identical shared secret key in different ways? Or do I need to write a similar method manually?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `crypto_scalarmult()` should not be directly used as a key. It has to be hashed, preferably with other data known by both parties, such as the involved public keys. See the libsodium documentation on [crypto_scalarmult()](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/advanced/scalar_multiplication.html), which also describes what `crypto_kx()` does.

That being said, the `scalarmult()` + hash + `secretbox()` sequence already exists in both libraries as a single high-level API, and is called `crypto_box()`.